# Getting Invalid Column Name for a Column that Does Exist?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm trying to populate tables in a database with values from another imported table in my database. Before using the INSERT INTO statement, I'm trying to just run the select statement on its own to verify that I'll get the right values, but running into this error. I've read a couple other threads on the same problem but can't figure out what is wrong with mine specifically.

(using Azure Data Studio, if that is useful info). Here is my code (screenshots linked below too) --

```
        SELECT DISTINCT 
        StateAbbr,
        [State],
        Longitude,
        Latitude,
        Zipcode,
        City,
        [Population]
    FROM BehaviorCoverageMerged b
        JOIN
            (SELECT
                Zipcode,
                City,
                [Population]
            FROM [2010ZipData]) z 
            ON [b].[StateAbbr] = [z].[StateAbbr];
    GO
```

I keep getting

> Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Line 14
> Invalid column name 'StateAbbr'.

The column does exist in the table in my database, so I do not know what the problem is. Does anyone know why this is happening? Attaching two screenshots as well - one of the query & error message, and another one of the table schema (where the column lives). Any help greatly appreciated!

[Query & error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UAury.png)
[Column names in table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HmeQh.png)

Comment: In the last line specifying the join conditions - `[b].[StateAbbr] = [z].[StateAbbr]` - the z.StateAbbr doesn't actually exists because z only has Zipcode, City and Population. You may want to use `(SELECT StateAbbr, Zipcode, City, [Population] FROM [2010ZipData]) z` instead of the current z.

Comment: You're joining a derived table that does not contain the required column, it's not part of the *select* list. There's also no need for a derived table, why are you not joining to the table?

Comment: Why use a derived table here at all? Why not just `JOIN` straight to the table `[dbo.]2010ZipData`? Also, might as well mention that that table name implies a flawed design.

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to select `StateAbbr` from `2010ZipData` in the

```
        SELECT DISTINCT 
        b.StateAbbr,           -- changed
...
                Zipcode,
                City,
                [Population]
                , StateAbbr  -- added
            FROM [2010ZipData]) z
```

but you should be able to just join without the 2nd select:

```
        SELECT DISTINCT 
        b.StateAbbr,           -- changed
        [State],
        Longitude,
        Latitude,
        Zipcode,
        City,
        [Population]
    FROM BehaviorCoverageMerged b
            FROM [2010ZipData] z 
            ON [b].[StateAbbr] = [z].[StateAbbr];
    GO
```